# Django on delete causes integrity error (models.set_null)

Tags: mysql, django

I have 2 models

```
class Foo(models.Model):
     field1 = models.Charfield()
     .... 
     ....

class Foo1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(Foo, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
    ...
```

When I try to delete the Foo object, it causes integrity error.

```
"'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"
```

I am using mysql backend and Django 1.7 ( I know this is old and I am trying to upgrade it to the LTS version. )

Edit: Please comment if you need more info. I will update it here.

```
Foo.objects.get(id=foo_id).delete()
```

This does not work. Causes the above said error. 
I just confirmed that the mysql Engine is Innodb.

Comment: Does both of your tables have the same engine in mysql? If one of them is MyISAM and the other is InnoDB it would cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and couldn't understand why the SET_NULL is not working as expected. I've eventually ended-up workarounding that by entering the django shell (*python manage.py shell*) and disconnecting the host objects before deleting the target objects.
In your example, it is mapped as following (assuming models.py is under catalog..):

```
% python manage.py shell

>> from catalog.models import Foo1
>> for obj in Foo1.objects.all():
>> ... obj.field1 = None
>> ... obj.save()
```

Then, you may safely delete the table, e.g.:

```
DELETE FROM catalog_Foo
```

BR,
Shahar.